# Old Isabelle project imports ml file using 'uses' How should I replace this?

Tags: ml, isabelle

I've inherited an old Isabelle project and would like to bring it up to date to work with Isabelle 2016. When the project starts a thy file it often starts:

```
theory my_theory
imports Main uses "my_theory.ML"
begin
lemma my_lemma: ...
by ...
end
```

The uses keyword doesn't seem to exist anymore so I've tried changing this to:

```
theory my_theory
imports Main
begin
ML_file "my_theory.ML"

lemma my_lemma: ...
by ...

end
```

This does include the file properly but I end up with errors within the ML file which may or may not be related such as: `Undefined fact: "my_lemma"` on a line of code with @{thm my_lemma}.

Is my change to include the ML file using `ML_file` command correct? and is this having an effect on the ML errors that I am receiving?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not familiar with the `uses` keyword; that must have been dropped some time before I started using Isabelle.

`ML_file` should be the way to go; however, you have to write `ML_file` *between* the `begin` and `end` commands that start/conclude the theory. Moreover, the `ML_file` invocation must be *after* the definition of anything that you use inside the ML file (constants, facts, theorem collections, simprocs, …)

In your example, it should look like this:

```
theory my_theory
imports Main
begin

lemma my_lemma: ...
  by ...

ML_file "my_theory.ML"

end
```

Note that Isabelle changes a lot. Any ML code that you have – especially if it is that old – will probably need a lot of changes before it works with modern Isabelle versions. It may well be easier to rewrite it from scratch. This is why Isabelle projects should be put into the [Archive of Formal Proofs](http://www.isa-afp.org/), where they are updated to any changes in the Isabelle system by the developers. Any Isabelle projects outside the AFP are likely to succumb to bit rot within a few years.